# Issues with inserting bibliography from Mendeley

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, warnings

I am new to LaTeX. I cannot import a saved bibliography from Mendeley to my LaTeX file. My current code reads this in the preamble:-

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\usepackage{color}
```

For the citations, it reads:-

`(\citealp{Rampino79}; \citealp{Hall82}; \citealp{Sigvaldason92};...)`

In the hope that it will appear in text as:- (Rampino et al., 1979; Hall et al., 1982; Sigvaldason, 1992...), and the bibliography as, e.g. Rampino,M., Self,S., Fairbridge, R. 1979. Can Rapid Climate Change Cause Volcanic Eruptions? Science. 206, 826-829.

The code under all my text reads as:-

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{LATEX}
\end{document}
```

With LATEX being the .bib filename produced by Mendeley, which is stored in my LaTeX folder, with the LaTeX files (.tex files).

I've tried a number of different methods, but still can't produce any type of bibliography, most likely because my code or bibliography is wrong. There are no errors in the text itself, but it suggests that 'thebibliography environment' is empty. I've also done the LaTeX > LaTeX > BibTeX > LaTeX thing and still nothing.

As a MWE, I hope this helps. I couldn't insert the code as a file you could open.. clearly not smart enough for this business!

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\begin{document}                                    

There is a strong body of evidence to suggest that a feedback mechanism between 
volcanic activity and climate change exists (e.g.\citealp{Rampino79};
\citealp{Hall82}}; \citealp{Sigvaldason92}; \citealp{Huybers09}; \citealp{Watt13}; 
\citealp{Rawson16}). Despite the abundant amount of literature on this topic.....
(\citealp{Rawson16}).

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{LATEX}

\end{document}
```

You have a screenshot of the .bib file. I am wondering whether it is because Mendeley has exported comments, though know it is likely because of many inabilities to code and there's probably more than one issue here, knowing me!

Sorry if this is a bad MWE! Let me know if you need more, and thanks for your quick help.

[image: Here is an image of some of the .bib file code]

[image: Error message from BibTeX]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you look at your `.bib` file, the keys are different from what you have in your TeX document: `.bib` = `Rawson2016` but `.tex` = `Rawson16`. These keys need to match, so you need `Rawson2016` in the `.tex` file (for all your keys it looks like). Also your second `\bibliographystyle` command will override the first, so you should keep only the one you want (`acm` or `plainnat`).

Comment: Thank you. It seems it now sometimes works and sometimes doesn't  - very temperamental. I got it to work using `\citealp` but now, for course, it won't work. I've just changed the code to `\cite` as I want to change the referencing style. I think this is because it is being temperamental, rather than that there is something fundamentally wrong. Do you find it to be the case that it is temperamental? I've been pressing LaTeX > BibTeX > LaTeX etc etc with no avail. Any ideas on how to improve bibliography output? I went with `plainnat`.